# Fancyhdr custom header failing for appendices

Tags: fancyhdr, appendices

let me preface this with saying I don't fully understand fancyhdr. I am trying to achieve getting the same header on every page: the left top showing the chapter number, section number and section title -- and the right top the page number. I.e.

- 1.1 section title
- 1.3 next section
- 2.1 new chapter
- bibliography (can manually switch styles for this)
- A.1 appendix section
- A.2 another appendix section

I can get this to work just fine in the normal chapters, but the approach fails when I use the 'appendix' package (which I use to achieve getting the 'appendix' entry in the TOC). A minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Include appendix
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

% Fancyhdr
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% Custom style:
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhead[L]{\thesection. \rightmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{The Ghost Problem}
\section{Bill murray}
Test
\newpage
\section{blockbusters}

% ============================================================================
% = APPENDICES ===============================================================
% ============================================================================

\clearpage
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Other disasters}
    \section{Godzilla}
    \newpage
    \section{Mordor}
    \newpage
    \section{Darth vader}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

If you compile this file, you'll find that the last page will show `1.3` rather than `A.3` in the header, basically falling back to the last know `\leftmark` information or so..?

If I use `\appendix` instead, this issue is not present. Any hints?

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE! Excellent first question with a good, compilable, MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just comment the `renewcommand` line and change `\fancyhead[L]` to something simpler.

```
% \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
```

Comment: Good, that fixes the numbering issue! I wrapped it in `\nouppercase{\rightmark}` to remove the smallcaps. Seems to work, thanks a lot! :-)